Finding player A folder
im using unity and According to the documentation https://docs.unity3d.com/2022.3/Documentation/ScriptReference/PlayerPrefs.html I should be able to find player preferences at "HKCU\Software\ExampleCompanyName\ExampleProductName".
But when I search my whole pc for a folder called "hkcu" I get nothing.
so im basically trying to find the folder.
this image shows everything I have described.

extra info
Each time I make a build player prefs from a previous build seem to persist. But this time I want to test my build fresh, and experience the game as a new player would. So I want to delete all my player prefs.

HKCU is a Windows Registry hive, it's not a folder on your PC.  It is short for HKEY_CURRENT_USER.  You can use the Windows Registry Editor to see what's stored there.

You can also run this in Powershell to see the values (replacing "ExampleCompanyName" and "ExampleProductName" with your values from your project):
Get-ItemProperty -Path HKCU:\Software\ExampleCompanyName\ExampleProductName

A word of caution: Do NOT edit anything in the Windows Registry if you are unfamiliar with it and what it does.  You can very easily render your system unusable if you update the wrong thing.

Thank you :)
. spot on
